# Does anyone have drivers for a TP-Link TL-WN823N USB wireless

Tags: wireless, usb

I have installed Ubuntu 13 on my system and I have been using a TP-Link TL-WNB23N USB adapter for my wireless on the WIN8 side...  They have drivers up at TP-Link for Win/7/8 but not for Linux.  Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lsusb.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 003: id 05e3:0722 Genesys Logic Inc., Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter,,,  Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:00dd Microsoft Corp. Comfort Keybaord 2000 V1.0, Bus 005 Device 002: ID 17ef:602e Lenovo, the remainders are root hub devices.

Comment: I don't see my USB devices.  Also When I do  a system test, for USB it doesn't see my Wireless device.

Comment: Except my Keyboard, mouse and my kingston stick.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

The TL-WN823N WLAN USB stick bases on the Realtek chip set RTL8192CU.  You can download the driver from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2772).

Comment: The driver rtl8192cu is already included in Ubuntu 13.04. Isn't it loaded? Please check: lsmod and iwconfig

Comment: lsmod shows a rtl8192CU, rtlwifi, rtl8192c_common

Comment: iwconfig shows etho no wireless extensions, lo no wireless extension., wlan0 IEEE 802bgn ESSID:off/any Mode:Managed Access Point: not-associated TX-Power 20 dBm retry long limit:7 RTS thr=2347 B fragment thr:off Power Mangement:off

Comment: My windows side when I boot it uses the chip/network.  Ubuntu says I am out of range or refuses to connect.

Comment: also the ifconfig -a shows a wlan0 being present, up broadcast multicast MTU:1500

Comment: I have found that if I unplug it and move it to another USB slot that it will connect for a short while, but after about 20 minutes or so it will show connected but none of my web apps will connect thru.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
```

If succeeds, this will create the driver module file **8192eu.ko**

If the folder /lib/modules/YLV/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/8192eu 
doesn't exist (YLV = **Your Linux Version** ex: 4.13.30-generic) , create it and place the 8192eu.ko the compilation just created in it.

```
# Replace 4.13.30-generic to whatever your version is, find it with:
# uname -r

cd /lib/modules/4.13.30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek
sudo mkdir 8192eu
sudo cp ~/my-dir-where-i-compiled/8192eu.ko 8192eu
```

Then test it, unloading the current driver, in my case it was rtl8xxxu:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8xxxu
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Doing this the wifi got with 54Mb and 100/100 quality

If fine, blacklist the old driver, adding a string to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf

```
blacklist rtl8xxxu
```

**Adding the module to initrd**

Add the name of the module to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules.

```
8192eu
```

This will add the module to the initrd file. 
Update the initrd file

```
update-initramfs -u    
reboot
```